# VBA Excel to Mac - file path

Tags: excel, vba, macos

The person that previously had my job used VBA in Excel on PC to create reports to track the finances in the office. It takes info from multiple workbooks. I would like to run it on a Mac. I moved all the relevant files to my computer. I know I need to update the file paths but I am lost even doing that.

The current file path looks like:
Application.Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\Chris Treeman\My Documents\Dept MathCS Financials\Accounting Files\Dept. Fund Tracking\Daily Compass Report Files\" & "CFSPPSUM - " & SpecifiedDate & ".xls")

I have copied the path from my Mac using Get Info. Would this be correct?
Application.Workbooks.Open ("/Users/robert/Documents/Reporting/Dept MathCS Financials/Accounting Files/Dept. Fund Tracking/Daily Compass Report Files/" & "CFSPPSUM - " & SpecifiedDate & ".xls")

OS X El Capitan Version 10.11.3
Microsoft Excel for Mac 2011 Version 14.5.9

Below is the code from the main module.

```
Sub Test()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Dim i As Integer
i = 6

Dim SpecifiedDate As String
SpecifiedDate = Cells(4, ActiveCell.Column)
SpecifiedDate = Format(SpecifiedDate, "mm/dd/yyyy")
SpecifiedDate = Replace(SpecifiedDate, "/", "-")

Dim TWB As Workbook
Set TWB = ThisWorkbook

Col = ActiveCell.Column

'CFSPPSUM Data Transfer

Application.Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\Chris Treeman\My Documents\Dept MathCS Financials\Accounting Files\Dept. Fund Tracking\Daily Compass Report Files\" & "CFSPPSUM - " & SpecifiedDate & ".xls")

While TWB.Worksheets("Import-Data").Cells(i, 3).Value <> "END"
On Error Resume Next
    TWB.Worksheets("Import-Data").Cells(i, Col) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(TWB.Worksheets("Import-Data").Cells(i, 3).Value, _
Workbooks("CFSPPSUM - " & SpecifiedDate & ".xls").Worksheets("Output Data Sheet").Range("$E$9:$AA$100"), 23, False)

i = i + 1
Wend
Cells(6, ActiveCell.Column).Select

Windows("CFSPPSUM - " & SpecifiedDate & ".xls").Close (False)

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
Sub Test_Final_Build()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

If ActiveCell.Row = 6 Then

Dim SpecifiedDate As String
SpecifiedDate = Cells(4, ActiveCell.Column)
SpecifiedDate = Format(SpecifiedDate, "mm/dd/yyyy")
SpecifiedDate = Replace(SpecifiedDate, "/", "-")

Dim TWB As Workbook
Set TWB = ThisWorkbook

Col = ActiveCell.Column

Dim NSPLoc As String, NSPL As Integer
NSPLoc = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("NSP SUM", Range("B1:B200"), 0)
NSPL = NSPLoc
Dim D831020Loc As String, D831020L As Integer
D831020Loc = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Dept. 831020", Range("B1:B200"), 0)
D831020L = D831020Loc
Dim SPPISUMLoc As String, SPPISUML As Integer, NSPISUMLoc As String, NSPISUML As Integer
SPPISUMLoc = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("SPP I-SUM", Range("C1:C200"), 0)
SPPISUML = SPPISUMLoc
NSPISUMLoc = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("NSP I-SUM", Range("C1:C200"), 0)
NSPISUML = NSPISUMLoc

Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer, l As Integer, m As Integer, n As Integer, o As Integer, p As Integer, q As Integer, r As Integer, s As Integer, t As Integer, u As Integer
i = 6   'SPP Sum Location
j = 6   'NSP Sum Location
k = 6
l = 6
m = 6
n = 6
o = 6
p = 6
q = 6
r = 6
s = 6
t = 6
u = 6


    'CFNSPSUM Data Transfer
Application.Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\Chris Treeman\My Documents\Dept MathCS Financials\Accounting Files\Dept. Fund Tracking\Daily Compass Report Files\" & "CFNSPSUM - " & SpecifiedDate & ".xls")
While TWB.Worksheets("Import-Data").Cells(j, 3).Value <> "END"
On Error Resume Next
    TWB.Worksheets("Import-Data").Cells(j, Col) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(TWB.Worksheets("Import-Data").Cells(j, 3).Value, _
    Workbooks("CFNSPSUM - " & SpecifiedDate & ".xls").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("$E$11:$BI$150"), 57, False)
    j = j + 1
Wend
    Windows("CFNSPSUM - " & SpecifiedDate & ".xls").Activate     'Sum Total Check Figure Import
        Sheets("Sheet1").Select
            Range("BI106").Copy
    TWB.Sheets("Import-Data").Activate
        Cells(NSPISUML, ActiveCell.Column).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Windows("CFNSPSUM - " & SpecifiedDate & ".xls").Close (False)


    'CFSPPSUM Data Transfer
Application.Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\Chris Treeman\My Documents\Dept MathCS Financials\Accounting Files\Dept. Fund Tracking\Daily Compass Report Files\" & "CFSPPSUM - " & SpecifiedDate & ".xls")
While TWB.Worksheets("Import-Data").Cells(i, 3).Value <> "END"
On Error Resume Next
    TWB.Worksheets("Import-Data").Cells(i, Col) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(TWB.Worksheets("Import-Data").Cells(i, 3).Value, _
    Workbooks("CFSPPSUM - " & SpecifiedDate & ".xls").Worksheets("Output Data Sheet").Range("$E$9:$AA$100"), 23, False)
    i = i + 1
Wend
Windows("CFSPPSUM - " & SpecifiedDate & ".xls").Activate        'Sum Total Check figure import
    Sheets("Output Data Sheet").Select
        Range("AA80").Copy
    TWB.Sheets("Import-Data").Activate
        Cells(SPPISUML, ActiveCell.Column).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Windows("CFSPPSUM - " & SpecifiedDate & ".xls").Close (False)


    'Dept. 831020 Data Transfer
Application.Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\Chris Treeman\My Documents\Dept MathCS Financials\Accounting Files\Dept. Fund Tracking\Daily Compass Report Files\" & "Dept. 831020 - " & SpecifiedDate & ".xls")
While TWB.Worksheets("Import-Data").Cells(k, 3).Value <> "END"
On Error Resume Next
    TWB.Worksheets("Import-Data").Cells(k, Col) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(TWB.Worksheets("Import-Data").Cells(k, 3).Value, _
    Workbooks("Dept. 831020 - " & SpecifiedDate & ".xls").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("$E$10:$AY$100"), 47, False)
    k = k + 1
Wend
Windows("Dept. 831020 - " & SpecifiedDate & ".xls").Close (False)


    'Dept. 831021 Data Transfer
Application.Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\Chris Treeman\My Documents\Dept MathCS Financials\Accounting Files\Dept. Fund Tracking\Daily Compass Report Files\" & "Dept. 831021 - " & SpecifiedDate & ".xls")
While TWB.Worksheets("Import-Data").Cells(l, 3).Value <> "END"
On Error Resume Next
    TWB.Worksheets("Import-Data").Cells(l, Col) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(TWB.Worksheets("Import-Data").Cells(l, 3).Value, _
    Workbooks("Dept. 831021 - " & SpecifiedDate & ".xls").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("$E$10:$AY$100"), 47, False)
    l = l + 1
Wend
Windows("Dept. 831021 - " & SpecifiedDate & ".xls").Close (False)


    'Dept. 831022 Data Transfer
Application.Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\Chris Treeman\My Documents\Dept MathCS Financials\Accounting Files\Dept. Fund Tracking\Daily Compass Report Files\" & "Dept. 831022 - " & SpecifiedDate & ".xls")
While TWB.Worksheets("Import-Data").Cells(m, 3).Value <> "END"
On Error Resume Next
    TWB.Worksheets("Import-Data").Cells(m, Col) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(TWB.Worksheets("Import-Data").Cells(m, 3).Value, _
    Workbooks("Dept. 831022 - " & SpecifiedDate & ".xls").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("$E$10:$AY$100"), 47, False)
    m = m + 1
Wend
Windows("Dept. 831022 - " & SpecifiedDate & ".xls").Close (False)


    'Dept. 831023 Data Transfer
Application.Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\Chris Treeman\My Documents\Dept MathCS Financials\Accounting Files\Dept. Fund Tracking\Daily Compass Report Files\" & "Dept. 831023 - " & SpecifiedDate & ".xls")
While TWB.Worksheets("Import-Data").Cells(n, 3).Value <> "END"
On Error Resume Next
    TWB.Worksheets("Import-Data").Cells(n, Col) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(TWB.Worksheets("Import-Data").Cells(n, 3).Value, _
    Workbooks("Dept. 831023 - " & SpecifiedDate & ".xls").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("$E$10:$AY$100"), 47, False)
    n = n + 1
Wend
Windows("Dept. 831023 - " & SpecifiedDate & ".xls").Close (False)


    'CFNSPS01 Data Transfer
Application.Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\Chris Treeman\My Documents\Dept MathCS Financials\Accounting Files\Dept. Fund Tracking\Daily Compass Report Files\" & "CFNSPS01 - PROVOST BAYH-DOLE RESTRICTED S" & SpecifiedDate & ".xls")
While TWB.Worksheets("Import-Data").Cells(o, 3).Value <> "END"
On Error Resume Next
    TWB.Worksheets("Import-Data").Cells(o, Col) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(TWB.Worksheets("Import-Data").Cells(o, 3).Value, _
    Workbooks("CFNSPS01 - PROVOST BAYH-DOLE RESTRICTED S" & SpecifiedDate & ".xls").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("$E$11:$BI$200"), 57, False)
    o = o + 1
Wend
Windows("CFNSPS01 - PROVOST BAYH-DOLE RESTRICTED S" & SpecifiedDate & ".xls").Close (False)


    'CFNSPS02 Data Transfer
Application.Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\Chris Treeman\My Documents\Dept MathCS     Financials\Accounting Files\Dept. Fund Tracking\Daily Compass Report Files\" & "CFNSPS02 - N16 SCIENCE HIRE INITIATIVE" & SpecifiedDate & ".xls")
While TWB.Worksheets("Import-Data").Cells(p, 3).Value <> "END"
On Error Resume Next
    TWB.Worksheets("Import-Data").Cells(p, Col) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(TWB.Worksheets("Import-Data").Cells(p, 3).Value, _
    Workbooks("CFNSPS02 - N16 SCIENCE HIRE INITIATIVE" & SpecifiedDate & ".xls").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("$E$11:$BI$200"), 57, False)
    p = p + 1
Wend
Windows("CFNSPS02 - N16 SCIENCE HIRE INITIATIVE" & SpecifiedDate & ".xls").Close (False)


    'CFNSPS03 Data Transfer
Application.Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\Chris Treeman\My Documents\Dept MathCS Financials\Accounting Files\Dept. Fund Tracking\Daily Compass Report Files\" & "CFNSPS03 - MICHELANGELO GRIGNI START-UP F" & SpecifiedDate & ".xls")
While TWB.Worksheets("Import-Data").Cells(q, 3).Value <> "END"
On Error Resume Next
    TWB.Worksheets("Import-Data").Cells(q, Col) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(TWB.Worksheets("Import-Data").Cells(q, 3).Value, _
    Workbooks("CFNSPS03 - MICHELANGELO GRIGNI START-UP F" & SpecifiedDate & ".xls").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("$E$11:$BI$200"), 57, False)
    q = q + 1
Wend
Windows("CFNSPS03 - MICHELANGELO GRIGNI START-UP F" & SpecifiedDate & ".xls").Close (False)


    'CFNSPS04 Data Transfer
Application.Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\Chris Treeman\My Documents\Dept MathCS Financials\Accounting Files\Dept. Fund Tracking\Daily Compass Report Files\" & "CFNSPS04 - CLS J Taylor" & SpecifiedDate & ".xls")
While TWB.Worksheets("Import-Data").Cells(r, 3).Value <> "END"
On Error Resume Next
    TWB.Worksheets("Import-Data").Cells(r, Col) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(TWB.Worksheets("Import-Data").Cells(r, 3).Value, _
    Workbooks("CFNSPS04 - CLS J Taylor" & SpecifiedDate & ".xls").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("$E$11:$BI$200"), 57, False)
    r = r + 1
Wend
Windows("CFNSPS04 - CLS J Taylor" & SpecifiedDate & ".xls").Close (False)


    'CFNSPS05 Data Transfer
Application.Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\Chris Treeman\My Documents\Dept MathCS Financials\Accounting Files\Dept. Fund Tracking\Daily Compass Report Files\" & "CFNSPS05 - Equipment - Taylor" & SpecifiedDate & ".xls")
While TWB.Worksheets("Import-Data").Cells(s, 3).Value <> "END"
On Error Resume Next
    TWB.Worksheets("Import-Data").Cells(s, Col) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(TWB.Worksheets("Import-Data").Cells(s, 3).Value, _
    Workbooks("CFNSPS05 - Equipment - Taylor" & SpecifiedDate & ".xls").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("$E$11:$BI$200"), 57, False)
    s = s + 1
Wend
Windows("CFNSPS05 - Equipment - Taylor" & SpecifiedDate & ".xls").Close (False)


    'CFNSPS06 Data Transfer
Application.Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\Chris Treeman\My Documents\Dept MathCS Financials\Accounting Files\Dept. Fund Tracking\Daily Compass Report Files\" & "CFNSPS06 - SOM Equipment" & SpecifiedDate & ".xls")
While TWB.Worksheets("Import-Data").Cells(t, 3).Value <> "END"
On Error Resume Next
    TWB.Worksheets("Import-Data").Cells(t, Col) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(TWB.Worksheets("Import-Data").Cells(t, 3).Value, _
    Workbooks("CFNSPS06 - SOM Equipment" & SpecifiedDate & ".xls").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("$E$11:$BI$200"), 57, False)
    t = t + 1
Wend
Windows("CFNSPS06 - SOM Equipment" & SpecifiedDate & ".xls").Close (False)


    'CFNSPS07 Data Transfer
Application.Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\Chris Treeman\My Documents\Dept MathCS Financials\Accounting Files\Dept. Fund Tracking\Daily Compass Report Files\" & "CFNSPS07 - JACKSON MATH AND SCIENCE FUND" & SpecifiedDate & ".xls")
While TWB.Worksheets("Import-Data").Cells(u, 3).Value <> "END"
On Error Resume Next
    TWB.Worksheets("Import-Data").Cells(u, Col) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(TWB.Worksheets("Import-Data").Cells(u, 3).Value, _
    Workbooks("CFNSPS07 - JACKSON MATH AND SCIENCE FUND" & SpecifiedDate & ".xls").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("$E$11:$BI$200"), 57, False)
    u = u + 1
Wend
Windows("CFNSPS07 - JACKSON MATH AND SCIENCE FUND" & SpecifiedDate & ".xls").Close (False)

TWB.Sheets("Import-Data").Activate
Cells(6, CLoc).Select

TWB.Sheets("Dept. NSPs & SPPs").Activate
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Columns(ActiveCell.Column).AutoFit

Else
    MsgBox ("Please select the correct cell for Import")
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Word of warning - you are on a dangerous path if you have inherited items which you don't have a technical understanding of. I recommend you make a concerted effort to learn VBA if you are going to be expected to work with it. Personally, you are at risk of code failing for any reason and being unable to fix it, making yourself accountable for any errors that code failure could cause. If you can't read the code, don't run the code.

Comment: Take heed to @Grade'Eh'Bacon's advice. However, if you want to dig in and learn VBA, there are some differences between MAC and PC versions. In your specific case see `Application.PathSeparator`. It's different on a mac vs pc as well as how the root folders are built.